# Do I need SEIKI SE39UY04 latest firmware for resolution to work on my Mac?

Tags: mac, hdmi, displayport, firmware

I am a bit late to the party here... I procrastinated far too long in getting the firmware updates, for my 2 SE39UY04 monitors... to the point that SEIKI no longer has them available...

I find myself in a predicament, where I have a "MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)" that I am trying to have it display a 4k 30Hz image on my Seiki monitor(s)...

Symptoms:
The monitor(s) sometimes try fo generate a 2160 resolution at first when the mac login screen is displayed, monitor will show on the upper right: "3840x2160 @30HZ" and the login screen is indeed a 2160 image, but once logged in, resolution reverts 1920x108@60Hz...

I tried getting specific mini display port to HDMI cable that is speced out for a 4k signal, but to no avail...

Given that the monitor does try to generate a 2160p image, I concluded that the outdated firmware on the SEIKIs is at the heart of the matter, and not the mini display port to HDMI cable... (as described on this conversation...

All that to say and hope there is ***ANY*** chance that someone has fingerprinted this firmware or knows of another modification that can make this older device work with my Mac. I don’t want to download drivers from the internet without some idea it’s original or untampered with.

Any options to keep using my gear?

Comment: Two monitors?   In that resolution?  Are you certain that the graphics card in the machine supports that?

Comment: At the moment I have just one monitor connected, would just like to see the 4k resolution work with one monitor...